# undefined local variable or method `pdf' for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf-generation, prawn, prawnto

I'm trying to generate a **pdf** file in rails with **Prawn**!
as explained [here](http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2008/10/13/how-to-generate-pdfs-in-rails-with-prawn/)

Exactly the same!
but I've Got this Error :

```
undefined local variable or method `pdf' for #<#<Class:0x005619ea6fecd0>:0x005619e9f54660>
```

for this line!

```
pdf.text "Hello World!"
```

It seems It doesn't **understand** the 'pdf.' 
Could you possibly help me ??
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: in which file you are using pdf.text "Hello World!"?

Comment: the guid you are using is pretty old and might be outdated > try this one http://www.idyllic-software.com/blog/creating-pdf-using-prawn-in-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: @power I'm using it in show.pdf.prawn file in veiw

Comment: @Nimir I tried this before and it worked properly but I have problems in Generating Tables in PDF file So i decided to use this solution instead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I myself Found the answer Let's review Together.
this is my controller

```
def show
  @resume = current_user.resume
end
```

this is my view (button):

```
<%= link_to t(:ExporttoPDF) , resume_path( :format => "pdf"),class:"btn btn-danger btn-lg"%>
```

and i added all of these gems to my gem file!

```
 gem 'prawn_rails'
 gem 'prawn'
 gem 'prawn-table', '~> 0.1.0'
 gem 'prawnto'
```

and this is my **show.pdf.prawn** file in resume view!

```
pdf.text "Hello World!"
```

and it dose work like a charm!
**Note**: I think my controller had some problem :)